# How do I specify a value nested in an array in a Mockoon rule?

Tags: mocking, mockoon

I'm trying to mock different responses in mockoon based on `value1` in the following body request:

```
{
"foo":"bar",
"records" : [{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2"
  }
]
}
```

The logical approach would have been to point as `records[0].key1` to compare the value, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

A little reading goes a long way.

The answer for my case is as follows:

```
records.0.key1
```

This is from the **Adding response rules** from the Mockoon documentation, https://mockoon.com/docs/latest/route-responses/dynamic-rules/:

> body:
> keep empty to match against the full raw body content.
> use a path to access one of its properties. The syntax is based on the object-path library like users.0.name. This is compatible with request's bodies of Content-Type application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/xml, application/soap+xml or text/xml. Properties containing dots are supported by escaping the dots: key.key.with.dot.
> Please note that XML bodies are parsed using xml-js package. Refer to this page or the package documentation for more information on how the XML is parsed and how to fetch specific properties.
> Please also note that multipart/form-data only supports fields. Uploaded files will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the dot notation `records.0.key1`, Mockoon also supports JSONPath. So, you should be able to fetch an array element by using the following syntax:

`$.records[0]`